# Spinner's onItemSelected method is not being called. (Update to title)

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a TextView text change based on the selected item from a Spinner. How do I do that?

I've looked at some YouTube videos and about 50 pages on StackOverflow. I have tried a bunch of different things such as switching position from the spinner to change the TextView, seeing if a specific string was selected from the spinner and using that to change the TextView, but nothing seems to work. 
If a user selected "Inches to Centimeters" on the spinner, I need the `conversionFrom` TextView to make it say "Inches" and the `conversionTo` `TextView` to say "Centimeters" and so forth.

> **Edit:**
>
> I tried making a spinner class and using that but still didn't call
>   the onItemSelect method.

```
  public class MeasurementConverter extends Activity implements TextView.OnEditorActionListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    // defining variables for widgets
    Spinner spinner;
    private EditText measurementInput;
    private TextView conversionFrom;
    private TextView conversionTo;
    private TextView convertedNumber;

    private double milesToKilo = 1.6093;
    private double kiloToMiles = 0.6214;
    private double inchToCent = 2.54;
    private double centToInch = 0.3937;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        measurementInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.measurementInput);
        conversionFrom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.conversionFrom);
        conversionTo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.conversionTo);
        convertedNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.convertedNumber);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = 
        ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.typeArray, 
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        calculateAndDisplay();
    }

    public void calculateAndDisplay()
    {
        // get the input
        String input = measurementInput.getText().toString();
        double inputAmount;

        if(input.equals("")) {
            inputAmount = 0;
        }else {
            inputAmount = Float.parseFloat(input);
        }

        // miles to kilometers todo
        // kilometers to miles todo
        // inches to centimeters todo
        // centimeters to inches todo
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

        if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_UNSPECIFIED){
            calculateAndDisplay();
        }
        return false;
     }

     @Override
     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int 
     position, long id) 
      {
        switch(position)
        {
            case 0:
                conversionFrom.setText("Miles");
                conversionTo.setText("Kilometers");
                break;
            case 1:
                conversionFrom.setText("Kilometers");
                conversionTo.setText("Miles");
                break;
            case 2:
                conversionFrom.setText("Inches");
                conversionTo.setText("Centimeters");
                break;
            case 3:
                conversionFrom.setText("Centimeters");
                conversionTo.setText("Inches");
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
  }
```

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">MeasurementConverter</string>
    <string-array name="typeArray">
        <item>Miles to Kilometers</item>
        <item>Kilometers to Miles</item>
        <item>Inches to Centimeters</item>
        <item>Centimeters to Inches</item>
    </string-array>
    <string name ="conversion_From"></string>
</resources>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/conversionTextView"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Conversion"
                    android:textSize="26dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:entries="@array/typeArray" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/conversionFrom"
                    android:layout_width="135dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textSize="20sp"/>

            <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/measurementInput"
                    android:layout_width="228dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:ems="8"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textSize="22sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/conversionTo"
                    android:layout_width="136dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="@+id/conversionTo"
                    android:textSize="20sp"/>

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/convertedNumber"
                    android:layout_width="228dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text="10.52"
                    android:textSize="20sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The `conversionFrom` textview is always blank. 
The `converstionTo` textview is always false.
Maybe I'm missing a piece of code to make it visible?

My problem before this(that I fixed) was that no text was showing on the Spinner at all. To fix that I finally found a solution. This guy had `android:entries="@array/typeArray"` in his Spinner XML file, which made my text show up on the Spinner. So maybe I'm missing something here to change the TextView text's.

Comment: I suggest debugging by putting a breakpoint in your 'onItemSelected' method and make sure it is being called when the spinner is changed.

Comment: Yeah, onItemSelected is not being called. How would I be able to fix that

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your app? I want to confirm something.

Comment: Sure it's in the link on the bottom